# CSS Glyphs not working with MaxCDN or caching services

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, cdn

I am using the CSS glyphs that are included in the template next to the menu items. Using these, a small icon can appear next to the name, and an arrow will appear next to it if it contains multiple items.

However, whenever I install a caching plugin or MaxCDN (I just tested it by turning on MaxCDN), they quit working in Firefox and IE 9-11 (I think in non-webkit based browsers). Oddly, they work with these plugins not activated.

Firefox
Before:

```
.icon-envelope:before {
content: "";
}
```

After:

```
.icon-envelope:before {
content: "";
}
```

Chrome
Before:

```
.icon-envelope:before {
content: "\f0e0";
}
```

After:

```
.icon-envelope:before {
content: "\f003";
}
```

These compare what the browsers show in the developer inspect tools before and after the application of MaxCDN. These glyphs are through Font-Awesome, but the joomla template doesn't directly use the bootstrap.css (so I don't think using bootstrapCDN will help).

Comment: Do you have a site link?

Comment: christar.org, but it works now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely due to CORS.  MaxCDN has an article on how to add a Access-Control-Allow-Origin header to HTTPD, Nginx & IIS here: http://support.maxcdn.com/howto/use-cdn-with-webfonts/

Firefox blocks webfonts from rendering if the following http header is missing:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks! That fixed it! --then I found this: http://support.maxcdn.com/tutorials/htaccess-examples/ which was helpful